# Can I use a variable storing a regular expression wherever a regular expression is expected?

Tags: awk

In Awk, when I store a regular expression in a variable, can I use the variable wherever a regular expression is expected?

The AWK Programming Language by Aho says

> Note that the string-matching pattern
>
> ```
> /Asia/
> ```
>
> is a shorthand for
>
> ```
> $O ~ /Asia/
> ```

I have a text file:

```
$ cat f1
line 1; li
ne
2
line 3
lin
e 4
```

Why do the following two ways work

```
$ awk -v pat='in' '{if (match($0, pat)) print $0; } ' f1
line 1; li
line 3
lin
$ awk -v pat='in' ' $0 ~ pat {print $0} ' f1
line 1; li
line 3
lin
```

while the following doesn't

```
$ awk -v pat='in' ' pat {print $0} ' f1
line 1; li
ne
2
line 3
lin
e 4
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't replace the syntax `/pattern/` with a variable `pat`.

Comment: Is there a rule governing that?

Comment: @Tim The grammar for the language disallows it. What you have in your non-working example is an expression that evaluates to true (it's non-zero), therefore all lines are printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `/foo/` alone is short for `$0 ~ /foo/`.

In `... ~ /.../` or `match(/.../, ...)`..., it's only some form of quoting operator for regexps, while in other contexts, it's more an operator that resolves to a number (0 or 1).

That double meaning can be a bit confusing. There are a lot of those double meanings / ambiguities in `awk`.

`/foo/` expands to 1 or 0 depending on whether `$0` matches the `foo` regexp or not but `"1" ~ /foo/` is not `"1" ~ "1"` when `$0` happens to match `foo`, here `/foo/` is no longer short for `($0 ~ /foo/)`. In the case of `"1" ~ (/foo/)` or `"1" ~ +/foo/`, you'll see the behaviour varies between implementations though.

`var` is only `var`.

`var` as a condition means true if the variable is numeric or a numeric string and resolves to a number other than zero or if it's a string and resolves to a non-empty string.

variables declared with `-v var=value` are of those that may considered numeric strings if they look like numbers and strings otherwise.

```
awk -v var=in 'var {print "x"}'
```

prints `x` for every record because `in` doesn't look like a number and is not the empty string.

```
awk -v var=0 'var {print "x"}'
```

Would not print `x`, while:

```
awk 'BEGIN{var = "0"}; var {print "x"}'
```

would print `x` for every record as `var` was explicitly declared as a string variable. So even though it looks like a number, it's not considered as such.

That's another one of those double meanings. A variable may be considered as numerical or string depending on context.  See also `>` that depending on context is taken as a comparison operator or a redirection operator (which again several ambiguous situations where the behaviour varies between implementations).

Note that you can also do things like:

```
awk '{print /foo/ + /bar/}'
```

Which is the same as:

```
awk '{print ($0 ~ /foo/) + ($0 ~ /bar/)}'
```

But if using concatenation instead of `+`

```
awk '{print /foo/ /bar/}'
```

that doesn't work as there's again an ambiguity between the `/RE/` operator and the `/` division operator. When in doubt, use parens:

```
awk '{print (/foo/) (/bar/)}'
```

By the way, you should avoid using `-v` to store regexps or anything that may contain backslashes, as ANSI escape sequences are expanded in them  (with GNU `awk` 4.2 or above, [values that start with `@/` and end in `/` are also a problem](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants)). Instead, you should use environment variables:

```
RE='\.txt$' awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["RE"] {...}'
```

for instance.

Comment: Thanks. (1) If I am correct,  in a pattern-action statement, the pattern can be an expression which can be a regular expression or not a regular expression. So using a variable as a pattern is not using it where only regular expression is expected. That's the reason of it not working. (2) For `RE='\.txt$' awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["RE"] {...}'`, can I just use `awk -v RE='\\.txt$' '$0 ~ RE {...}'` (doubling the backslash) equally well?